# How to combine two dictionaries into one

Tags: typescript

I have an array of dictionaries, which contain information about apps version:

```
appsVersion = [
               {"adroid_version": 0.0.150, "ios_version": 0.0.150},
               {"adroid_version": 0.0.150, "ios_version": 0.0.151},
               {"adroid_version": 0.0.162, "ios_version": 0.0.152},
               {"adroid_version": 0.0.162, "ios_version": 0.0.152}
               ]
```

My aim is to aggregate this data into the following way:

```
aggregatedData = {
"version 0.0.150": {"android_version": 2, "ios_version": 1},
 "version 0.0.151": {"android_version": 0, "ios_version": 1},
 "version 0.0.152": {"android_version": 0, "ios_version": 2},
 "version 0.0.162": {"android_version": 2, "ios_version": 0},
}
```

Could you help me to manipulate this data, please? I am writing on TypeScript

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses a complete version of the TypeScript syntax:

```
function aggregateData(
    appVersions: { android_version: string, ios_version: string }[]
): {
    // Declare the output type of the function
    [version: string]: {
        android_version_count: number;
        ios_version_count: number;
    }
} {
    // Declare and initialize an object we will be populating
    let aggregatedDataOutput: {
        [version: string]: {
            android_version_count: number;
            ios_version_count: number;
        }
    } = {};
    // Both initializes a version entry and creates a new one if one doesn't exist
    function getVersion(version: string) {
        let versionObj = aggregatedDataOutput[version];
        if(versionObj === undefined) {
            versionObj = {
                android_version_count: 0,
                ios_version_count: 0,
            };
            aggregatedDataOutput[version] = versionObj;
        }
        return versionObj;
    }
    
    // Add all app versions to aggregated data
    for(let appVersion of appVersions) {
        getVersion(appVersion.android_version).android_version_count++;
        getVersion(appVersion.ios_version).ios_version_count++;
    }

    // Additionally, sort by key (version)
    let aggregateEntries = Object.entries(aggregatedDataOutput);
    aggregateEntries.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a[0] < b[0]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(a[0] > b[0]) {
            return +1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    aggregatedDataOutput = {};
    for(let [key, value] of aggregateEntries) {
        aggregatedDataOutput[key] = value;
    }

    return aggregatedDataOutput;
}

let appsVersion = [
    {"android_version": "0.0.150", "ios_version": "0.0.150"},
    {"android_version": "0.0.150", "ios_version": "0.0.151"},
    {"android_version": "0.0.162", "ios_version": "0.0.152"},
    {"android_version": "0.0.162", "ios_version": "0.0.152"}
];

console.log(aggregateData(appsVersion));
```

Let me know if any parts of this are confusing. If the TypeScript syntax is confusing you might want to go through some TypeScript tutorials, they do a better job explaining than I can. I recommend https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html .

Also if you are completely new to TypeScript, you may find this page useful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial . I'm not sure what kind of editor you are using, but VS Code has very good TypeScript support and can assist with informing you of syntax errors inline.

Comment: wow, that's massive! Thank you, I'm going to try this!